# Javascript form submit POSTs no data

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

This is the form I'm using to post the data to `gamelobby.php`

```
<form id="game_form" method="POST" action="/gamelobby.php">
    <input type="text" id="plr_name"></input>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="table_name"></input>
</form>
    <button id="codefight_create">Create a Fight</button>
```

This is the function that submits the form

```
    function codefight_create(){
            // blah blah, some ajax
            table_name = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("table_name").value = table_name;
            document.getElementById("game_form").submit();
            // console.log(table_name);
        }
    document.getElementById("codefight_create").addEventListener("click", function(){
        codefight_create();
    });
```

The problem is that when I `var_dump($_POST)` on the `gamelobby.php` page, there is no data stored in the `$_POST` superglobal on the page.

Comment: Could you post the blah blah blah some ajax? I suspect the problem in this part

Comment: It is not, the `table_name` variable is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the name for the `input`:

```
<input type="text" id="plr_name"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="plr_name" name="plr_name"></input>
```

(same for the `table_name` `input`, the `id` is only on the client-side, it doesnt get sent to the server)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="game_form" method="POST" action="/gamelobby.php">
...
</form>
<button id="codefight_create">Create a Fight</button>
```

to

```
<form id="game_form" method="POST" action="gamelobby.php">
...
<input type="submit" value="Create a flight"/> 
</form>
```

Add on click event by onclick="codefight_create();" on the button input.
You can use listener event but you need to add it into the the JQUERY when the document gets ready..

Comment: I have also tried that, it returns the same result. Plus, I need the javascript functionality.

Comment: do it like 
<button id="codefight_create" onclick="codefight_create();">Create a Fight</button> <--this will call the function

Comment: you can use add listener event only but you need to add it into the document.ready.

Comment: It is right before the closing `</body>` tag, so it is not neeeded.